# how to pass a collection object in response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, xml, jsp, session

in a jsp page say x.jsp ,i have

```
if (some task =true)
{
//show xml at run time
List <User_Registration> list = dao.selectemailmobile(login); //here m getting data from  Db and m getting it perfectly alright
response.sendredirect("page.jsp?list="+list)
//i wanted to pass this list parameter as List<Bean> list=List<Bean>();
//this page will show xml at run time

}
else 
{
//some status code 
//this working fine 
}
```

**what i tried**

1.pass this(List) parameter as list i have shown,but when i'm retrieving it, is says

```
 cannot cast from string to List<Bean>
```

for that i also tried to type cast it,but nothing happens.

2.setting that List in **session** it shows

```
unchecked cast from object to List<Bean>
```

3.using request Dispatcher

```
 i get same cannot cast from string to List<Bean>
```

my code for that xml page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="com.xml.*" %>
<%@page import="com.beans.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>


<%@page import="com.xml.ForgotPasswordXml"%>
<%!java.util.List<User_Registration> list= null; %>
<%try{
HttpSession session2=request.getSession();
System.out.println("hii");

list=(List<User_Registration>)request.getAttribute("list");
//list=(java.util.List<User_Registration>)request.getParameter("list");
System.out.println(list.toString());
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
<%=ForgotPasswordXml.xml(list)%>
```

any help would be appreciated.thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the list in session as

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("list",list);
```

And in the next page retrieve the list as

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Bean> list = (List<Bean>) request.getSession().getAttribute("list");
```

or

```
List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<Bean>();  
list.addAll(session.getAttribute("list"));
```

Note the type cast, it will avoid Type mismatch exception.

And if the list isn't needed further, remove it from the session as (optional)

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("list");
```

Comment: i can't remove as i have to use this list to pass to a variable which will return me the string ,that i'll show as xml.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 removing the list from session depends on the nature of the application. Thats y I marked it as optional.

Comment: still its giving an error .unchecked cast from object to List<Bean>

Comment: can you try putting @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") with List

Comment: i'm unable to put that warning ,as its type:safety check.also its giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception.i tried to increase the heap size also but it didn't not works.

Comment: The method addAll(Collection<? extends User_Registration>) in the type List<User_Registration> is not 
 applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Seems something is wrong with your `List` declaration , Can you post your model class

Comment: @sankrish i have modified the code how i m getting data in list.

Answer (score 0):

Send the whole List as one JSON string and rebuild the List using the JSON .
You need to use JSONObject . The other thing you can do is , set List to Session and get back the List from the session and invalidate the Session if requires .

Comment: i dont want to use JSON as i m fetching data from the DB in to a list which i have to pass

Comment: in that case use RequestDispatcher and use forward method , there you can send the List .

Comment: i have tried that but its not working m getting and error *unchecked cast from object to List<Bean>*